# Image urls retrieved using facebook graph api break after certain amount of time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, facebook-graph-api, koala

I have a rails(ruby 2.2.1, rails 4.2.0) application that uses the koala gem (2.0.0) to retrieve all the images from all the albums for the user. The code for the facebook service is as

```
class FacebookService
 attr_reader :graph

 def initialize(token)
   @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(token)
 end

 def photos
   your_photos, photos_of_you = [], []

   albums_ids.map do |album_id|
     #this query will combine fetch all the photos in any album + comments + likes associated with that image
     your_photos += graph.get_connections(album_id, "photos", {limit: 100, fields: ["id", "source", "images", "height", "width", "created_time", "likes", "comments{id, message, from{name, picture}, created_time}"]})
end

     photos_of_you = graph.get_connections("me", "photos", {limit: 100, fields: ["id", "source", "images", "height", "width", "created_time", "likes", "comments{id, message, from{name, picture}, created_time}"]})

     (your_photos + photos_of_you).flatten
   end

   def albums_ids
     albums.map { |album| album["id"] }
   end

   def albums
     graph.get_connections("me", "albums")
   end
 end
```

and has been used as

```
fb = FacebookService.new current_user.oauth_token
photos = fb.photos
```

I am saving those urls in the db for further reference. I tried saving the **source** and the largest image from the **images** array but the urls keep going invalid. The problem is that when the above code is executed, the urls in the **source** and **images** aren't valid after certain amount of time(say 2-3 days). How can I retrieve image url that don't break later?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a short-lived or long-lived User Access Token?

Comment: long lived(60 days) user access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filed [a bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/526758397365834/) about this one a while back - it appears it's by design, and that there's some reason for those expiring URLs. The solution here is to actually cache image data, rather than just a URL.

Comment: I am checking if the "id" of the image is constant and doesnt change as the url does. If so, i plan to save the id too and update the url. If the above option doesnt work, i plan to download the image onto the server. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yeah - the ID is constant. Save the ID, and grab the image url for that ID just before you need it :)

Comment: @TomWaddington Is it possible to get the id of current profile picture using koala??